# Does the System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog Class OpenFile() method give the string to the property of the FileName property

Tags: c#

I just have another question which people have referred me of asking in a different topic so here goes as concrete as possible.

The `OpenFileDialog` class is derived from the `FileDialog` class. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.openfile?view=netcore-3.1) is the URL.

My question is, it seems to say that the openfile method returns a stream. However does it also say it stores what is returned in the `FileName` property? Or does this `FileName` property have nothing to do with the `OpenFile()` method. What I mean is, it seems I can access the `FileName` property after selecting a file without any problem, without calling the `OpenFile()` method and I still have the `FileName` after selecting a file manually running the program.
So if the property `FileName` isn't filled with the `OpenFile` method, how is this done then?
Thank you!

Comment: The `FileName` property gets its value from the `fileNames` array (which stores the paths of the selected files that can be accessed via the `FileNames` property). Now, the `fileNames` array's value is set by a private method named [`DoFileOk()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/FileDialog.cs,3af9feefde304408) which [gets called](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/FileDialog.cs,805) when the "OK" button of the dialog is clicked. Hope that helps.

Comment: Perfect thanks Ahemed and how could I have found this out for myself?? Did you just use MSDN?

Comment: Well, it's pretty easy to _guess_ that the filename(s) are set when the "OK" button is clicked after calling the `ShowDialog()` method (think about it for a second; when else could it happen?). However, to get this exact information, I had to look at [the source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/).

Comment: Note that the `OpenFile` method has nothing to do with all that. It simply creates a FileStream for the [first] selected file. Which is something you can do manually using `new FileStream(openFileDialog1.FileName,....)`.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed. I didn't know there was this reference online. This was very helpful

Comment: You're welcome! BTW, the links in my first comment take you directly to the relevant parts of the code.